# fstream .open and appending .txt or .dat to filename

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c-str

This has worked fine on some compilers... Is there a way of doing this were it will just work without it being a problem with different compilers on c++11 or c++14?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void save_file() {
    string file;
    ofstream os;
    cout << "Save As: ";
    getline(cin, file, '\n');
    os.open(file + ".dat");
    //rest of code
}
```

error: no viable conversion from 'basic_string, std::allocator >' to 'const char *'

So I google it, found some answers, or in this case, canswers (cancers), tried

```
os.open(file.c_str() + ".dat");
```

error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const char *' and 'const char *')

Comment: Wait. Don't you do this in the `main`?

Comment: its in a function, sorry forgot to include that part

Comment: always provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Also, where is the error, what line?

Answer (score 1):

Accoding to the C++11 standard 27.9.1.10 one of the constructors for a basic_ofstream is:

```
explicit basic_ofstream(const string& s, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out);
```

This means that any standard compliant compiler should be able to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string file = "temp";
    ofstream os;
    os.open(file + ".dat");
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b62e6caebf4cd4b7)

Don't forget that you need to use the `-std=c++11` or higher flag when compiling.

Comment: And pre-C++11, you could still concatenate and call `.c_str()` on the results.

Answer (score 1):

"+" operator cannot be used for the C-style strings. Try this:

```
string name = file+".dat";
os.open(name.c_str());
```

You create the std::string type as a concatenation in c++ style and then pass it to open as a c string.

Comment: no problem ^^, mark this as an answer please so it's clear for the others

Comment: apparently I don't have the rep to do that! sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, `os.open( file + ".dat" )` works just fine.  Pre C++11, there was no `std::ofstream::open` which took a string, so you had to write `os.open( (file + ".dat").c_str() )`. Note the parentheses and where the `.c_str()` goes---you have to concatenate with the `std::string` first, and only call `.c_str()` on the results.

Comment: confirmed:  this worked   os.open((file + ".dat").c_str());